# Use of Parameter in where clause in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I am struggling to put @parameter with where clause.

Actually my requirement is to display data for both months Jan and Feb in report when they both are selected from parameter checkbox.

I am using 
`Union All select Months from table where @MonthSelected = 'Jan' AND @MonthSelected ='Feb'`

I want to combine that both in where clause, if both are selected than only it will display data as needed or else not.

But I facing challenge in writing that where clause with @MonthSelected along with AND.

Please help me if anyone is aware.

Thank you

Comment: can you show your actual query? are you trying to do an union for each month that is supplied as parameter value? So in theory.. 12 unions???

Comment: As Harry said you will need to show your actual query. Show what you would write if you just had to hardcode a query to get the same results, that might help us understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Harry ```Union All
select 'Jan-Feb' as Months, [Coulumn1Name], [Coulumn2Name], Count(distinct[Coulumn3Name]) as 'Column', Count([Coulumn4Name]) as ' Col',  from [Table]
where ((@MonthSelected = 'Jan' OR @MonthSelected = 'Feb') and Coulumn1Name is not null and [Coulumn6Name]='Paid' and [Amt]>0) 
group by [Coulumn1Name],[Coulumn2Name]```        When I am putting OR with @MonthSelected Parameter it is working but as I am putting AND it is giving me error ------ An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. this is the error I am receiving.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have pasted the query in comment section

Comment: @Harry Thank you for looking into it

Comment: @AlanSchofield thank you for looking into it

Comment: @Harry The starting query for report is ```Select Months, [Coulumn1Name], [Coulumn2Name],Count(Distinct[Coulumn3Name]) as 'Column', Count([Coulumn4Name]) as ' Col' from [Table]
where Months in (@MonthSelected) and Coulumn1Name is not null and [Coulumn6Name]='Paid' and [Amt ]>0 
group by Months, [Coulumn1Name],[Coulumn2Name] ``` --------------------- this is the first query and Union all query is after first query and I have almost 11 or 12 Union all connected to the main query... thank you